# File copy works in eclipse testing environement but produces URI error in packaged program

Tags: java, file, io

I have a program that needs an excel file which could be modified by the user, so I've included a copy into the classpath just in case the one that can be altered manually would dissapear. The idea is that the first time you run the program, the file included into the package it's copied to another folder where the user will be able to edit it.

When I run the test with eclipse, the copy is actually done. The source that does it is this:

```
    public static void createExcelIfNotExists() throws URISyntaxException, IOException{
    File fOrigin = new File("doc\\Data.xlsx");

    if(fOrigin.exists()) 
        return;     

    fOrigin = new File(ExcelDataProcessor.class.getResource("dt.xlsx").toURI());
    File fDestiny = new File("doc\\Data.xlsx");

    OutputStream o = new FileOutputStream(fDestiny);

    Files.copy(fOrigin.toPath(), o);
}
```

[image: Eclipse folder structure]

As I said, in the eclipse testing environement it's OK, the problem comes when i export the project into a .jar file. Despite the fact the folder doc actually exists and the package actually contains the `dt.xlsx` document, when I run the program, the file is not placed there.

When I run the program, the error I get is the one in the picture

```
d:\Jar>java -jar prog.jar
creating directory: logs
DIR created
creating directory: records
DIR created
creating directory: doc
DIR created
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
        at fileDataProcessing.ExcelDataProcessor.createExcelIfNotExists(ExcelDataProcessor.java:101)
        at menus.MainMenu.initializeDirectoriesAndConfigFiles(MainMenu.java:880)
        at menus.MainMenu.main(MainMenu.java:859)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Any hint on how the problem come from in URI or how I could solve it?

Comment: Do not post a screen shot of your output.  Copy and paste the actual text into your question.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the suggest, done.

Answer (score 2):

When your program is packaged int a JAR file, the files on your CLASSPATH are inside the JAR file's ZIP archive.

That being said, you can use [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) method to access a file on the CLASSPATH.
But cannot use the above version of `Files.copy()`...

Comment: You know there exists [more than one Files.copy method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-), right?  He most certainly can use Files.copy, just not the one that accepts two Paths.

Comment: Could you suggest a file copy method?